# Since I updated the Unity editor version to the last beta I can't find the unity packages. Is that a bug?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image: Packages]

Where is the Standard package or the characters package ?

Answer (score 1):

It can now be found in the package manager.

Go to Window -> Package manager.

You can then switch between the "in project" tab and the "all" tab. 
Your characters package should be listed in the "all" tab. Hit install/ update in the top right corner to get it.

Comment: It's not there. I see the All tab and see all the packages. But the characters package is not in the list.

Comment: Have you expanded the initially collapsed "Built in packages" menu under All?

Comment: I tried everything in the Package manager it's not there. Can't see there the Characters or Environment. It's not exist in the Package manager.

Comment: In the older version I used so far 2018.2.5f1 it is exist. Assests > Improt Package and it's there built in. In the beta version 2018.3.0b it's not exist not built in. And I will not start downloading the package/s for each project. I'm just going back now to the older version.